# Why min function with lambda just return 1 parameter?

Tags: python

In this following code which I think its has the same semantics,but it return different result for me.

```
a=range(5)

#expression 1

b=min(a,key=lambda x:x<3)

print(b)

#output:3

#expression 2

c=[x for x in range(5) if x<3]

print(c)

#output:[0,1,2]
```

In my option I think that in expression 1 when x in lambda expression `x=3,false=(x< 3)`, then the function `min()` can find the value of [True,True, False,False] in listing `a` and return value compared to the first value when x<3 is false,but i dont sure isn't true.

Comment: The `key` isn't used to define filtering afaik. It defines how the elements of the collection should be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what the `key` parameter to `min` is for.

That parameter decides how values in your iterable will be compared, as in the following example:

```
iterable = [{'name': 'Bert', 'age': 23, 'height': '175'},
            {'name': 'Harold', 'age': 47, 'height': '169'}]
print min(iterable, key=lambda x: x['age']) #=> {'name': 'Bert', ...}
print min(iterable, key=lambda x: x['height']) #=> {'name': 'Harold', ...}
```

What seems to have tripped you up here, though, is that booleans in Python are comparable; `False < True`. This means that `min(a, key=lambda x: x<3)` will give you the element of `a` which yields the smallest result from `x<3`, so you might get any of the values for which that expression yields `False`.